# Wired network disconnected by NetworkManager - how to fix?

Tags: 11.04, networking, network-manager

Ubuntu 11.04, classic desktop. Hardware is working fine, and network was working previously, but after changing my location (and rebooting the machine), Ubuntu just says 'Wired Network Disconnected'. Router shows working connection, and booting to XP gives a working network.

What could I try to fix this?

ifconfig shows eth0 interface with an IPV6 address only.

edit:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:8f:81:88:89  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0xe800 

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# This file is installed into /etc/NetworkManager, and is loaded by 
# NetworkManager by default.  To override, specify: '--config file' 
# during NM startup.  This can be done by appending to DAEMON_OPTS in 
# the file:
#
# /etc/default/NetworkManager
#

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Okay, new info: ifdown eth0 says

> ifdown: interface eth0 not configured

Comment: Please paste the output of the following 3 commands: `sudo ifconfig eth0`, `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: Also, `sudo dhclient eth0` and try to disable and renable networking in NetworkManager. (independent ideas, not sequential)

Comment: ifdown eth0 ; ifup eth0 ; dhclient eth0 ( all as root) may work. Else check your syslog file ( sudo less /var/log/syslog ) may give u an idea why u do not get an IP

Comment: I managed to get network connectivity by manually adding the gateway, a known working dns, and the ipv4 address. Network Manager still doesn't show a connection, though.

Comment: I suspect this is really a bug in the ethernet driver used. Could you please add the output of ''lspci -vnvn''